# how to test if labels have actual dependencies on features?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am trying to train an LSTM(many to one) model with multivariate time series input and a categorical output.

after training for quite some time, the resulting model still has low accuracy and high loss on validation data. So started doubting that maybe the features I had chosen for predicting the label are simply irrelevant?

I wonder if there are methods for testing if the chosen features do have explanatory power on labels?

Before coming to stack exchange, I did some research online and found somebody saying we should be using PCA to test if labels are dependent on features, which confused me a lot. I thought PCA is used for dimension reduction on features and is irrelevant to labels. am I missing something here?

Below is an extract of what I just mentioned.

> 1. It is always a good idea first to make sure that the output (dependent) variable (target or label) actually depends on the input
>    variables (features). It is possible that you are chasing a ghost that
>    doesn’t exist. There is a way to check this, but before that, we have
>    step two.
> 2. Start by using the z-scores to normalize the input variables. Any normalizing would do but there is a reason for using z-scores. It has
>    to do with the next step. You can do a Principal Component Analysis
>    (PCA). It will tell you the contribution of each of the new variables
>    (obtained after the transformation) to the variation on the output
>    variable.
> 3. PCA will answer the question I mentioned at the outset about the existence of dependency clearly. Before performing PCA, the variables
>    have to be normalized using z-scores.

[source of the above extract](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-improve-the-accuracy-of-a-neural-network)

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/625461/247274)

Answer (score 0):

One quick way (if they are numerical and not categorical data) would be to create a correlation heatmap (like [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) library implements) and observe if any of the cells are particularly correlated with your label column. Of course, this is not a completely definitive method, because sometimes the correlations can span between columns, but it's worth a try.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-seaborn-correlation-heatmap-in-python/) is a good tutorial